# PubSub Event is not getting fired LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, pubsublwc

Hello Everyone can anyone pls help why I am not able to `console.log(apexParam)`, I am not even getting any alert and my `FireEvent` is also not getting fired

Cmp which is firing the event

HTML

```html
<template>
    <ul class="slds-has-dividers_bottom slds-has-block-links_space" >
        <li class="slds-item board-item productRow">
            <div class="slds-clearfix">
                <div class="slds-float_left slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <a onclick={navigateToDetail} target="_blank">{account.Name}</a>
                    Accid id  {account.Id}
                </div>
                <div class="slds-float_right slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_success" onclick={showRelatedList} name="contact">View Contacts</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_success" onclick={showRelatedList} name="Opportunity">View Opportunites</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

JS file

```js
export default class AccSearchResultWithCon extends LightningElement {
    @api account;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    showRelatedList(event){
        let buttonName = event.target.name;
        let accId = this.account.Id;
        console.log('Account Id',accId);
        console.log('Button Name',buttonName);
        if(buttonName ==='contact' || buttonName ==='Opportunity'){
            //alert('Button Name '+buttonName);
            let apexParam = {
                "aId" : accId,
                "btName" : buttonname
            };
            console.log('This is the apex param ',apexParam);
            alert(apexParam);
            fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'relatedlist' , apexParam);
        } 
     }
}
```

CMP who is subscribing the event

HTML

```html
<template>
    Hi this is the accont Id {accountId}
</template>
```

JS File

```js
export default class RealtedListTable extends LightningElement {
    @track accountId;

    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;

    connectedCallback() {
        registerListener('relatedlist', this.relatedListHandler, this);
    }

    relatedListHandler(data){
        let accid = data.aId;
        this.accountId = data.aId;
        console.log('This is the accId from Event',accid);
    }
    
    disconnectedCallback() {
        unregisterAllListeners(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please confirm additional details such as: 1. are you using the sample pub/sub code that Salesforce provided in the lwc samples; 2. are both components in the same lightning page; 3. are both components in the same namespace?

Comment: (Not showing the imports makes it harder to help you and omitting the pub/sub code detail does too)

Comment: hi @PhilW yes i am using the same pubusb and component is in the same lightning page

Comment: Same namespace?

Comment: And please edit the question to add the imports used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to get fire the event by doing the following

```js
     showRelatedList(event){
        let buttonName = event.target.name;
        let accId = this.account.Id;
        console.log('Account Id',accId);
        console.log('Button Name',buttonName);
        if(buttonName ==='contact' || buttonName ==='Opportunity'){
            //alert('Button Name '+buttonName);
           /* let apexParam = {
                "aId" : accId,
                "btName" : buttonname
            };
            console.log('This is the apex param ',apexParam);
            alert(apexParam);
            fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'relatedlist' , apexParam); */
            this.getRelatedList(accId,buttonName);
            
        }
        
    }

    getRelatedList(accountId,botName){
        console.log('This is Accont Id from ',accountId);
        let apexParam = {
            "aId" : accountId,
            "btName" : botName
        };
        console.log('This is the apex param ',apexParam);
        alert(apexParam);
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'relatedlist' , apexParam);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to import lightning/navigation and pubsub in your JS

```
import { NavigationMixin, CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { fireEvent } from 'c/pubsub';
```

JS method

```
export default class RealtedListTable extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
```

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: In that case, it should be something simple you are missing. It is hard for us to get to the bottom of this without looking at entire code. Please go ahead and complete this trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/lwc-build-flexible-apps/inter-comp-events. It should clear all your doubts.